# How to start and await multiple I/O operations at the same time without wasting threads in F#?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, f#

We know there is no point in running I/O operations in separate threads since they are "truly" asynchronous, meaning that they are non-blocking without requiring an extra thread to be run on.

Consider this scenario: I have an I/O function `insertProductAsync : DbModels.Product -> Async<unit>` and another I/O function `insertProductsAsync : DbModels.Product seq -> Async<unit>`. Both do exactly what they say they do and there is one condition: `insertProductsAsync` must use `insertProductAsync`. This is an educational example, so no need to discuss SQL batch operations and similar concepts.

The workflow I'm looking for for `insertProductsAsync` is as follows:

1. For each product, start an `insertProductAsync` task sequentially.
2. While the I/O operations execute, do not use or block the current thread, or any thread.
3. Finally, return a task or similar structure that completes when all the individual `insertProductAsync` tasks will have been completed. I believe in C# this could be achieved by doing the following:

```cs
public Task InsertProductAsync(DbModels.Product product)
{
    // pure 'async'/non-CPU-bound operation
}

public Task InsertProductsAsync(IEnumerable<DbModels.Product> products)
{
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks = products.Select(InsertProductAsync);  // tasks already started to execute, no extra threads used
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Which of the following options (if any) match the workflow I described and why? If none, please provide your own option with explanation. When explaining, please provide a good description of what happens behind the scenes.

## Option 1 — `Async.Sequential`

```fs
let insertProductsAsync (products : DbModels.Product seq) =
    async {
        return!
            products
            |> Seq.map insertProductAsync
            |> Async.Sequantial // each async block probably awaiting the previous one to complete, probably not what i want
            |> Async.Ignore
    }
```

## Option 2 — `Async.Parallel`

```fs
let insertProductsAsync (products : DbModels.Product seq) =
    async {
        return!
            products
            |> Seq.map insertProductAsync
            |> Async.Parallel // wasting threads probably, I guess
            |> Async.Ignore
    }
```

## Option 3 — ???

Your option here.

Comment: Assuming (in some ideal world) that database inserts are truly parallelizable, this seems like a good case for `Async.Parallel`. You can set the degree of parallelism manually if you're concerned about "wasting" threads. (I'm not even sure what you mean by that.)

Comment: Thanks, the question is not about parallelism or how optimizing the number of threads used. It is more about: "I have these I/O operations that I want to _start_ (but not necessarily complete) in parallel. I don't care about the order, but I do care when all of them have completed. I want to start them on the main thread where I would also be able to await for their completion".

Comment: This may not make sense, as the example is theoretical. If what I'm trying to achieve is non-sense, that's fine. The point is to have a better understanding of asynchronous workflows in F#.

Comment: I think you're describing `Async.Parallel`, so that's what I would use.

Comment: I think dotnet runtime takes thread management on itself, running multiple async operations in parallel doesn't necessary implies that they will be executed on multiple threads. It depends on a number of things, they can wait for some remote response mostly all the time of the async operation in the same thread for example.

Comment: @KonstSh Good point, that's kind of what I was aiming to understand. The answer is probably too low level for anyone to know exactly what's going on. What I assumed initially (although it may be wrong), is that each operation that executes in parallel **blocks a thread** as opposed to just being started on that thread and freeing it soon after. I still don't know if that's the case, but what you said makes sense. I'm dying to know though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your final question, operations that execute in parallel do not block a thread. That would be synchronous behavior. You can see this in the following example:

```ml
open System
open System.Threading

let doSomething timeout =
    async {
        Thread.Sleep(timeout : int)
        printfn $"Slept {timeout} milliseconds on thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"
    }

printfn $"Main thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"
doSomething 1000 |> Async.Start

printfn $"Main thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"
doSomething 900 |> Async.Start

printfn $"Main thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"
doSomething 800 |> Async.Start

printfn $"Main thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"
doSomething 700 |> Async.Start

printfn ""
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Output:

```
Main thread ID: 1
Main thread ID: 1
Main thread ID: 1
Main thread ID: 1

Slept 700 milliseconds on thread ID: 10
Slept 800 milliseconds on thread ID: 7
Slept 900 milliseconds on thread ID: 6
Slept 1000 milliseconds on thread ID: 4
```

Note that the main thread (ID 1) doesn't block during execution.

Comment: Yep operations that execute in parallel do not block a thread, but that's not what I believed. I just thought that each instance of my I/O operation running in its own thread within the context of `Async.Parallel` would block the thread it's running on, until it's complete -- that means one thread would wait for my I/O operation to complete. That seems not to be the case based on other comments.